# Computing linearized gravitational wave emission from point-like masses

Tags: gravitational-waves

I'm trying to compute the gravitational wavefront created from a set of moving masses. I'm trying to apply the equation

$$ h_{jk} = \frac{2}{r} \frac{d^2 Q_{jk}}{dt^2}$$

Where $h$ is the linearized perturbation of the metric and $Q$ is the quadrupole moment.

$Q_{jk} = \int{\rho(x) x^j x^k dx^3}$

My question is, would these equations be still valid for a bunch of point-like masses? the $\rho(x)$ would become a $\delta(x)$, and because of that $h$ would become zero everywhere except on the masses, so I wouldn't get a meaningful far field from these quantities

What would be the first-order approximation of GW emission from some moving point-like masses?

Comment: They would, but because $Q_{j k} = 0$ you would get no waves. You have to have a non-vanishing quadrupole mode to get gravity waves.

Comment: The $Q_{jk}$ are nonvanishing in general since they become a sum of terms like $M_{i} X_{i}^{j} X_{i}^{k}$, but this gives a single tensor quantity for all the system (at a given time t) while on the other hand, $h_{jk}$ should have different values on the whole spatial slice

Comment: The quadrupole moment is computed by integrating over _source_ coordinates. You should think of the quadrupole moment as a time dependent tensor quantity, but it is not localized at a point in space. So if you put a delta function source in, the quadrupole moment will be finite, since you integrate all space to compute the quadrupole moment. The $1/r$ is the observer coordinate at large distances from the source. So $h$ is being evaluated at a distance $r$ from the source. Does that help?

Comment: So, after I integrate all the quadrupole components, I'm left with 9 functions of time-only (all spatial dependence on the source has been integrated into the moments) So the $h_{jk}$ only spatial dependence is through the retarded potential from the quadrupole time derivatives. Is that right?

Comment: A detailed and nice discussion can be found here, http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March01/Carroll3/Carroll6.html